# Setting up monit to keep track of .sock files for php-fmp sites

Tags: php-fpm, monit, ubuntu-22.04

I'm trying to setup Monit so that it keeps track of domains in case PHP crashes. Example:

```
check file php7.3-fpm-pidfile with path /var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.pid
    start program = "/usr/sbin/service php7.3-fpm start" with timeout 60 seconds
    stop program  = "/usr/sbin/service php7.3-fpm stop"
    if does not exist then restart
    if failed unixsocket /run/php/php7.3-fpm-domain.co.uk.sock then restart
    if failed unixsocket /run/php/php7.3-fpm-domain2.co.uk.sock then restart
    if failed unixsocket /run/php/php7.3-fpm-domain3.co.uk.sock then restart
```

As a simple test:

```
check file php7.3-fpm-pidfile with path /var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.pid
    start program = "/usr/sbin/service php7.3-fpm start" with timeout 60 seconds
    stop program  = "/usr/sbin/service php7.3-fpm stop"
    if does not exist then restart
    if failed unixsocket /run/php/php7.3-fpm-domain.co.uk.sock then restart
```

However, the final fails when restarting Monit:

> /etc/monit/conf-enabled/php-fpm:14: syntax error ‘unixsocket’

I'm on **Monit 5.31.0**, which should be new enough to have the `unixsocket` option. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you will check a file, from my point of view you will check a process?

My suggestion to check the unixsocket and the process:

```
check process php7.3-fpm-pidfile with path /var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.pid
    start program = "/usr/sbin/service php7.3-fpm start" with timeout 60 seconds
    stop program  = "/usr/sbin/service php7.3-fpm stop"
    if does not exist then restart
    if failed unixsocket /run/php/php7.3-fpm-domain.co.uk.sock then restart
```

You can not use all available tests ("if" statements) with in all checks.

```
monit -v -t
Process Name          = php7.3-fpm-pidfile
 Pid file             = /var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.pid
 Monitoring mode      = active
 On reboot            = start
 Start program        = '/usr/sbin/service php7.3-fpm start' timeout 1 m
 Stop program         = '/usr/sbin/service php7.3-fpm stop' timeout 30 s
 Existence            = if does not exist then restart
 Unix Socket          = if failed /run/php/php7.3-fpm-domain.co.uk.sock type TCP protocol DEFAULT with timeout 5 s then restart
```

Snippet from the manual, see https://www.mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html

> CONNECTION TESTS
>
> Monit can perform connection testing via network ports or via Unix
> sockets. A connection test may only be used within a process or host
> service type context.

Connection tests are available with process or host services only.

Comment: Thank you !!!! That did it :)